# Python dependencies: Merging two packages into one

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have two python packages `A` and `B` that I would like to merge together into `A`, i.e. all functionality of `B` is now reachable in `A.B`. Previously, `A-1.0` depended on `B-1.0`. Now I want to avoid, that users of `A-2.0` still have `B-1.0` installed and I don't know how to handle this properly.

Different solutions/ideas I came up with:

- Include some code in `A-2.0` that tries to import `B`, if an ImportError is raised, catch the exception and go on, otherwise throw a RuntimeError that `B` is installed in parallel
- Somehow mark `B` as a blocker for `A-2.0` (**is this possible**?)
- Create a "fake" successor for `B`, so people who update their virtual environments or install the "latest" version of `B` get an empty package that throws an exception upon importing.

I welcome your opinion, and experiences

Comment: "A and B that I would like to merge together into A" - you created a problem for yourself by bypassing the package manager which does handle the dependencies properly. You should either have a compelling reason to merge them or not merge them at all.

Comment: This question would be much more clear if you made a table of (A.version, B.version, is_allowed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can't! (at least without using such tricks, as you described).

The Python package system has (to my knowledge) no such notion as "allowed" packages. There could be a person, that invents a different package C that he calls B, but with totally different functionality. Such a notion would prohibit users of your package A to use package C (alias B).

So I would communicate to users of A, that B is no longer needed and make sure, that your newer coding does not reference B at all. And when somebody installs B, it is like a third party library that has nothing to do with yours.

Of course, when the functionality of A and B is intermingled very much and the other user code also has to deal with B directly and has (allowed) side effects on A, you could get in trouble when an old B is still installed. But than your initial design was not the best either.

In such a case (and when you really have to merge the packages -- see below) I would recommend, that you make a totally new package name like "newA" to underscore the fact, that something has fundamentally changed (and thus an intermingling between old A and B also would more likely be detected).

But of course, I would second the argument of msw, that you create your problem by yourself. Normally it is also better to have smaller packages (if they are of a reasonable size, of course) instead of bigger "I manage the world" packages. You just can combine smaller packages better for different applications.